How to obtain Matplotlib plot finish time?
I have a function that generates a 2-D array of complex numbers and then plots them on a scatter plot using pyplot. The arrays are large, typically 256x256, and the plotting can sometimes take well over a minute. So for several reasons I'd like to know how to measure how long that takes. If it's relevant to the question I'm working with Spyder.
I'm successfully using datetime.datetime.now() to pick up the start and finish times for the code that creates the data, and have another datetime.datetime.now() right at the end of my file after the code that calls the plot. But the time which that returns is not the time at which Matplotlib finishes the plot. Matplotlib continues to plot long after my own code seem to have finished execution. How can I pick up the time at which Matplotlib actually finishes plotting?
Although marked as a duplicate the most highly rated answers I was referred to seem to suffer the same problem that I reported above. Simplified code example below with 1-D random data:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import time
n=8192
mag=np.random.rand(n)
angle=2*np.pi*np.random.rand(n)
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(projection='polar')
ax.set_ylim(0,1)
start = time.time()
print(start)
for m in range(0,n):
    c = ax.scatter(angle[m],mag[m],c=2,s=0.01)
end = time.time()
print(end)
print(end-start)    
print("Finished.")   

The above code reports an (end-start) time of about seven seconds, and that result is printed in the Spyder console about forty seconds before Matplotlib has actually finished the plot. So it is not the answer that I'm looking for.

If the linked duplicate doesn't work for you, please provide a [mre] that demonstrates how it doesn't work

As requested I've edited the question and explained that the answers to the earlier questions did not help. It seems that my question is still valid.
